# Connect my arduino with ethernet shield to new router

Tags: ethernet

I just changed the router for my webserver and I'm having trouble to connect my arduino with the LAN.
I'm using a router which uses Zhone technology, and I've been working with NetGear for a while without problems.
The procedure I've done so far is:

1. Connect the arduino with the ethernet and run the DhcpAdressPrinter example
2. Once I got the adress, in my case 192.168.1.125 I run the WebServer example, using the IP assigned by the DHCP.
3. In the serial monitor, I see it has started the program with the correct IP.

Problem: WHEN PUTTING THE IP INTO A BROWSER, NOTHING CHARGES

More info:

- In my router page (192.168.1.1) I can see that each ethernet port has
  assigned a MAC adress, I don't really understand why.
- I also can see that the arduino has been successfully added to the DHCP with the IP assigned and the MAC adress that I wrote on the code
- Finally, add that I've read in another website that sometimes the problem is due to the fact that the router just let the access to some specific MAC adress, but i'm not sure.

Any help will be apreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to strip down the problem to a tiny test snippet to share?

Comment: Can other devices on the same ethernet connections communicate with your PC?

Comment: If there is something maybe wrong with your MAC, you should: 1)Make sure your cellphone can connect normally. w) change your IP to your cellphone's, and close your phone's wifi connection. Then try arduino program again. This idea mainly is based on using your phone's known-as-available mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was capable to solve it by just creating a port forwarding with the IP that was assigned by the DCHP. 
It looks like my router for security reasons don't let you comunicate with other devices within the lan, so it's necessary to open a port and access the device through it!

Comment: Sounds like "wireless isolation" to me - which is where I was heading with my comment above.

Comment: Yes you are right Makenko, I think this is the correct term :)